# is copying code from jsFiddle too minor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, source-code, jsfiddle, too-minor

When I see a question with a jsFiddle link, but without any code, I always edit the question and copy-paste the code from the fiddle. My [last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2352261) almost got rejected. The interesting thing is that one user meant the changes were "too minor" and the other one - "too much". I totally disagree that changes were "too much" as I didn't change the code, but I'm not sure if they were really too minor. If there is nothing else to improve, should I copy-paste the code or not?

Comment: You know &*^$'s going down when you edit gets rejected both for being *too* ***major*** and *too* ***minor***. FWIW, I'd have approved your edit, and see nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the link to the fiddle breaks (or the fiddle website is down), the post is useless. But if you copy the content in the post it will stay like this forever.

So your edit changes a post from a potentially useless post into a valid one. That is **not** *too minor*.

Comment: But it also misses some of the other problems with the post, which could have been edited at the same time. It's slippery in this case.

Comment: I was going for the general question about copying a fiddle. Not for the particular case. BTW the *Thanks* was removed too in the edit. Persoanlly I'm not sure if I would have removed the *"There must be something wrong. I don't know what?* line.

Answer (score 5):

I would have approved your edit, but made some improvements as there are a couple of things you missed, such as removing the `"There must be something wrong. I don't know what?"` line, which is nothing more than 'noise'.

In general, edits that pull code from a fiddle into the question are fine, but make sure your edit addresses as many problems with the post as possible.