# How do I get my Gravatar image?

Tags: support, profile-picture, gravatar

With the news that [the Stack Exchange network may lose access to your avatar image from Gravatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370187/130940) if your email address changes. Is there a simple way to copy the image from Gravatar?

Answer (score 7):

You can log into gravatar.com using your email address (if you're like me you'll have to go over the Lost Password flow as I hadn't logged into Gravatar since 2008)

Then you get to a Manage Gravatars page

[image: Manage Gravatars Page]

where you can save your image by clicking on the image and then doing "Save Image As...".

You can, if you want to, disable your gravatar using the option on the menu

[image: disable gravatar]

that will get you here

[image: disable gravatar take two]

Answer (score 7):

In the light of the potential user image change here on stackexchange, you can save the profile picture you are currently using.

Go to your profile, right click on your image and select `Save Image As...`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to Python, this short piece of code will get the image from Gravatar and pop it up in your default browser.  You should be able to do a Save-As from there.

`gravatar.py`:

```py
import hashlib
import webbrowser

def ghash(email, fixcase=True):
    if fixcase:
        email = email.lower()
    return hashlib.md5(email.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

def open(email, size=80, fixcase=True):
    h = ghash(email, fixcase)
    url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?size=%d&d=identicon' % (h, size)
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: You can also log into gravatar.com using your email, download the image there and optionally shut your Gravatar account down if you've no use for it anymore.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic that's worthy of a new answer.