# Why is my identicon different from the one that shows up in Edit Profile > Change Picture > Identicon?

Tags: support, bug, gravatar, identicon

I don't know when this started, but now, when I go to edit my profile and look at the "Change Picture" menu, the identicon item's image is different than the identicon I actually get when I select that item. The identicon I actually get is just the same one I have always had since the beginning. It's the "Change Picture" menu's identicon that's changed. I haven't changed my account email. I did add another login method recently, but I thought that isn't related to the identicon.

Here's my "real" identicon image:
[image: my "real" identicon image]

And here's the one that shows in the "Change Picture" menu:
[image: the identicon image that shows in the "Change Picture" menu]

I noticed this yesterday.

Why is this happening? Is it a bug? Should I blame caching? (If so, why/how?)

I tried to look for a duplicate question / if a duplicate question existed searching [`is:q identicon -[discussion] -[feature-request] -gravatar`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=is%3aq%20identicon%20-%5bdiscussion%5d%20-%5bfeature-request%5d%20-gravatar), but didn't see anything that looked the same.

I did see [Why is my profile image different?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/997587) (2016-08-20), but my user account didn't even exist back then.

Comment: Different email hash, but we can't know if the bug is on SE side or Gravatar side. You probably have several emails attached to your Gravatar account.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204540/152859) in [Unexpectedly changing identicon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon), this might not be a bug:

> This is the default for new users, and for existing users **a salt is added as soon as they change their picture and select identicon**.

I've added emphasis around the relevant part: when you select identicon option, the system is changing the email hash on purpose (aka "adding salt") due to security concerns, hence resulting in a different final image.

Comment: Hmm. My oldest network account didn't even exist when the salt started being added, and this only started for me recently (see the question post).

Comment: As far as I know, it's added on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was related to changing your credentials, as they [announced in 2021 that changing your email will affect your gravatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370187/323179). However…

Here's what I see on my account:

[image: brown identicon option]

As you can see, the identicon I'm offered is not [either of the ones I had in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/323179) but a new brown one. (On Area51, my profile image is still the blue one I had in late 2016.) This is because it's using a [new gravatar link](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fa3eda09be653a40fcb0846a702c3e17?s=60&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1) and not the [old one](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc4984b955fd2b2105f6c9777b3eb3d4?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1).

I double checked and I haven't ever changed my email. It is just spontaneously different.

This seems to be most similar to when [SE first started adding salts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204523/323179) in 2013 (before my time).