# My identicon is switching automatically

Tags: support, identicon

Overnight my profile identicon is behaving weirdly. It is changing automatically and randomly: in fact switching to one form and another randomly.

Here are some snaps:

This is the original one:

[image]

The altered one along with the old one in chat:

[image]

Old & New and New & New:

[image]

[image]

Both beneath the same post:

[image]

[image]

The overall layout remains same but what is conspicuous is the change in the peripheral pattern.

Now, I am registered/logged in via a single email account, if that is important.

I don't have multiple accounts.

I use the site from more than one device but it has not been a problem until now.

I searched a bit but didn't find any post that addresses the issue.

Nothing too important to ponder about, but just little bit weird as to what is happening. Might be that but is trivial but it is new to me.

I have seen this post: [Why is my identicon different from the one that shows up in Edit Profile > Change Picture > Identicon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386019/why-is-my-identicon-different-from-the-one-that-shows-up-in-edit-profile-chang) but it doesn't say why the icons are switching interchangeably.

Comment: Did you see [Unexpectedly changing identicon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon)?

Comment: As I said, @AaronBertrand, I have looked into these relevant posts. But the point is mine has not changed. It is still both. They are switching by themselves. Just for instance, here beneath `asked` it is one identicon and at the top bar, it is another.

Comment: You only mentioned the first one, so, I was just checking.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. It's just that it is weird. I wonder whether that's one of a problem faced by a single user (me) or have been faced by other.

Comment: Could you post the URLs (right-click, open image in new tab, and copy that URL) for two instances of the identicon that are different for you in the same session, and also the URL(s) of the page(s) those were pulled from? This may help narrow down the issue (e.g. it may be a gravatar problem).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, as per your suggestion, I right clicked on the old identicon to open the image in a new tab only to see that the new tab has the new identicon and not the old one. As for the page, well I am seeing it in this very page itself.

Comment: Can you copy the URL and post it in a comment? If it's the same as what I'm seeing on all the pages I opened for you, then it's likely _only you_ are experiencing a caching issue, and we're not going to be able to do much about it, because it is likely happening somewhere between you and us and gravatar.

Comment: Here is the url: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3eaf3ebd89b38eb3eb56f86f3325fbd4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1. And this is the instance from this very [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0viOS.jpg).

Comment: I see the right one, so aside from legacy cache-busting techniques (shift+reload, loading the image and adding additional query strings, etc.), I'm not sure what else to recommend. When was the last time you cleared your browser's cache? hard reset your browser / machine / router/cable modem?

Comment: Well I have cleared the cache of my pc yesterday. I am using my phone now. I cleared the cache few hours ago. Same result in both devices.

Comment: In fact, I have switched browsers without any change.

Comment: That still doesn't rule out gravatar (have you reached out to them?), your ISP (have you tried rebooting your modem so you potentially get a new IP address and a fresh connection to _their_ CDN?), etc. Obviously if we give your browser a URL and it renders for you one way in that page and another way in a new tab, there's nothing _we're_ doing to cause that situation, and nothing we can do to resolve it.

Comment: I haven't rebooted my modem of late. Re gravatar, no, I haven't reached them. The whole issue happened today. So, I didn't get much time to react until now without being able to comprehend the same.

Comment: Anyway, thanks again @AaronBertrand, for bearing with my predicament.

Comment: I see the exact same identicon in all your screenshots, so not sure what you report here or what changed.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars, I have provided the snaps. I don't know what's going. In any case, the old one has changed not into a new but rather a minorly altered one.

Comment: In fact, I have looked into the other users of my community: their archived profiles and the new ones. The identicons have changed in a similar way. This is not a singular case.

Comment: I guess it is on the Gravatar's part. Unlike the old cases, this time the identicons have changed with minor tweaks.

Comment: Btw @ShadowWizardChasingStars, I didn't get why you are seeing the same identicon in my screenshots. They are different. Notice the periphery.

Comment: I honestly can't see any difference, but if others can, kudos. It's like the ability to distinguish between nearly identical shades of same color: I just can't do that, for me it's the same color.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars, I am sorry for that if I am not able to articulate the change. I have already said the changes are not drastic. The color has not changed. It is the peripheral pattern that has changed.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars the top one looks like a circular saw blade. The bottom one looks like a castle with two spirals and two moats.

Comment: @JamesRisner haha, you have good imagination, bet you also have the ability to see animals in the clouds, wish I had that. However yeah, think I might see some really tiny difference, very subtle and elusive, so maybe Gravatar just tweaked a number in their generator.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars, I think that is a plausible explanation.